# want give access only one component backend manager users?

Tags: php, joomla

I want give access only one component to the back end manager users? it is possible?if yes please tell me how can?

Comment: Think this belongs on Webmasters

Comment: look into ACL extensions

Answer (score 1):

The answer is within this post:
http://forum.joomlaworks.gr/tutorials-by-joomlaworks-and-other-expert-users/give-joomla-backend-managers-access-to-any-component!-control-who-has-access!/

It includes modifying the `includes/gacl.class.php` file, where all access rights sit.

Comment: consider marking this as the answer then

Comment: they said modify includes/gacl.class.php in that file.only one line coad available.